# Eclipse IDE not hot-deploying ressources after maven gulp build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gulp

I have a strange problem, after having setup my build pipeline in eclipse via maven. I will use my sass compiler for example, but this extends to my whole pipeline (js merging, font copying, etc.). Some snippets to boot:

Pom.xml

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>

        <executions>
            [...]

            <execution>
                <id>gulp build css</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>gulp</goal>
                </goals>

                <configuration>
                    <arguments>css</arguments>
                    <srcdir>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/sass</srcdir>
                    <outputdir>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/static/css</outputdir>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

gulpfile.js

```
[...]

gulp.task('css', function() {
  var scssSource = 'src/main/resources/sass/main.scss';
  var cssTarget = 'target/generated-resources/static/css/';

  // compile sass files
  var sassStream = gulp.src(scssSource).pipe(
          sass().on('error', sass.logError));

  // autoprefix and minify
  sassStream.pipe(autoprefixer({
    browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 10']
  })).pipe(concat('main.css')).pipe(gulp.dest(cssTarget)).pipe(
          rename(function(path) {
            path.basename += ".min";
          })).pipe(cleanCSS()).pipe(gulp.dest(cssTarget));
});
```

I confirmed the build pipeline to be working e.g. it produces the correct output. When looking at the maven console in eclipse I can see the build running successfully. I can even open the generated css files through the IDE in "target/generated-resources/static/css", and confirm changes made.

However - they are not populated (hot deployed) to an running application. Restarting the application, the changes are visible. I tried refreshing the folder manually in eclipse, but that yielded no success.

If I trigger the build manually, instead of relying on the watch mechanism of the maven plugin, the same happens. However, a refresh of the output folder (generated-resources here) populates the changes to the running application.

This is extremely annoying, since it delays front-end development a lot (running the build manually, refreshing the folder, etc.). I can also confirm that hot-deployment itself work. Static js/css files (which are not part of the fulp build) can be changed, with result immediately visible in the running application.

Answer (score 0):

You must refresh Eclipse workspace in order to do hot deployment.

Alternatively you can configure Eclipse for check changes automatically going to:

```
Window->Preferences->General->Workspace and check "Refresh automatically"
```

Or (depends of Eclipse's version)

```
Window->Preferences->General->Workspace and check "Refresh using native hooks or polling"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change anything :/ The maven build _should_ do the refresh. But aparrently, it doesn't. I see the following line in the build process: "Refreshing files after gulp: C:\TC GIT\timecontrol\timecontrol.webui\target\generated-resources\static\css".

I also ruled out the browser cache - just to be safe.